# Application insight request fails even though the code is working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I have an action method which is working as I expect. Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Content,Category,HeaderFilePath")] Blog blog, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            if (blog.HeaderFilePath != string.Empty && blog.HeaderFilePath != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/") + "images/" + blog.HeaderFilePath);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //TODO: handle it properly
                    //throw;
                }
            }
            blog.HeaderFilePath = Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";
            CustomHttpPostedFile f = new CustomHttpPostedFile(upload.InputStream, "jpg", HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/") + "images/" + blog.HeaderFilePath);
            f.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/") + "images/" + blog.HeaderFilePath);
        }
        db.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(blog);
}
```

This Action method is doing its job no problem, Am I missing something?

The sign above the method body looks like "0 references | 1 request, 100% failed | 0 exceptions".

When i click on it it doesnt provide me any usefull information.

Edit: here is the screenshot showing no information for the failed request.
[image: Missing information]

Comment: if you click that "1 request" CodeLens indicator, there should be an option in the window that pops up for "Search".  click that.  it will take you to the search results for that request, and see what the request status/response codes, etc are?  (i'm wondering if the "RedirectToAction" returns a response code that somehow is getting interpreted as failure?)

Comment: Unfortunatly, there is no search results when I clicked it. It still stays mistery. I tried to run it with and without the redirect and it makes no difference

Comment: can you send me an email to jgardner@microsoft with repro steps and screenshots so i can help you get to the bottom of this?  this seems very strange to me, so i'd like to help you fix it!

Comment: i tried to answer both this and the duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954702/why-is-application-insights-saying-i-have-a-failed-request-but-successful?noredirect=1&lq=1) with the same answer, but the answer here got deleted since it says i should raise the rest as duplicates. but i *can't do that* since neither answer was accepted or upvoted by anyone. :|

Comment: @JohnGardner - I edited my question providing screen shot when I click on the 'Search button'

Comment: yes, and both the screenshot here and the screenshot in the duplicate are the exact same result.  and i *still* can't make this a duplicate because nobody's upvoted the answer on the other one, and my answer here got deleted because it was a duplicate of *that* answer. :|  this appears to be a specific behavior around RedirectToAction according to that question.

Comment: @JohnGardner Well, i upvoted the answer in the other thread. I hope this will help you. I added the other thread to favs, hope we will find an answer somehow. Thanks for the effort, mate!