# Why is Application Insights saying I have a failed request, but successful

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights, directoryinfo

The request actually succeeds now, but AI says failed request. It took about 6 hours to get this working, i.e. creating the directory and putting data into the database. Not sure what AI's problem is.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this appears to be an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847828/application-insight-request-fails-even-though-the-code-is-working-properly but i can't mark it as a dup because there's no answer yet.  In that one, i asked for more information about the specific details of the request that it says failed.  if you can, send me email at jgardner@microsoft so we can try to track this down.  codelens will show it failed request if the query we do says it was submitted to telemetry as failed.

Answer (score 1):

the codelens indicator there does a query for requests the last 24 hours (or if not "configured" it is watching requests that went by *while debugging*).

if you click on it, it should have more information, and clicking the search link inside the popup will take you to a search window that has whatever failed request occurred.  *(but in general, see my comment above, need more info to accurately answer)*

Comment: Updated. I am 90% sure this has something to do with RedirectToAction;; I only use this in 2 controller actions and both indicate failure: return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); AND return RedirectToAction("Project", "Home", new { ProjectNumber = project_number }); I think it does redirect correctly but AI seems to have an issue, and provides no details for it.

Comment: can you create an issue on https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server with this info?